# Hash Sum mismatch(Metasploit)

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, metasploit

```
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Ubuntu Version: 16.04
Backbox: 5.2

Answer (score 2):

Try this on your terminal:

```
apt-get clean

rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

apt-get update
```

I hope this fix your problem

Comment: This solution did not work in my case. Is there another solution?

Comment: @xeon123 sorry if this solutions is not universal solution for your case. You might want to see this issue on metasploit'srepository: 
1. https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/issues/11421 
2. https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/issues/10574 
3. https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/issues/10595 

these issues might involved with mirror and CDN provisioning.